# I would like to make a pattern using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I would like to make a regex pattern ,I would like to make a pattern that get the value which is inside the brackets ,I tried this one but its not working.

```
String input = "(3+4)+5*4";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"([(0-9\/\+\-\*0-9)])");
if (m.Success)
{
    String value = m.Groups[1].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(value);
}
```

Comment: Instead of simply saying "it's not working," describe your expected and actual results.

Comment: ok I will make sure to do this next time,thank you for your advice :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are doing is mis-understanding what a "class" does in a regular expression.

```
[] - Denotes a set of characters to match.  This is NOT a pattern.
```

what you need to be grabbing is the pattern, which you did have nearly correct.

```
(\([0-9][\/\+\-\*][0-9]\))

Capture:
  Open Parenthesis
  Any character in [0-9]
  Any Character in [\/\+\*\-]
  Any Character in [0-9]
  Close Parenthesis
```

This will only allow one digit though.  If you have ANY multi digit number, even a 10...this wont work.  Now, if you changed it to something like this:

```
(\([0-9]+[\/\+\-\*][0-9]+\))
```

those `+` tell the regex to capture *One or More*.  This will allow any number, not just a single digit.

Comment: It works,thank you so much for your help and thank u for making me understand some thing that I wasn't understanding it well.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the pattern you are looking for:

```
"\(([0-9]+.?[0-9])\)S*"
```

You might have forgotten that brackets, parenthesis and "+" are special characters. Try [Regex Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/) or other regex testers to modify the pattern you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To help you further check out some of these sites. A very helpful site is [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1); they have a large library of Regular Expressions. They also have a [RegEx tester](http://regexlib.com/%28X%281%29A%28B3Q4M7yLueG7CUyR4V3rDIdPEA5sxUfmDdOaLcwVdHs6bVM4FTqJPf8j1Twils8q11MJdeRjEQ5hJsH9XmLXAmjD8X_a-MSdK-ZzACBElxc426HFHGi4JRH2V29n6CXEYieMajOx4xuceIgUKp6lJXpxvfdohNZW3wfGu2edCmUOLgA2IexbHSM42zyR-3sV0%29%29/RETester.aspx). Also a very useful RegEx tool is available [here](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).